# CSS Width won't apply to <ul> <li> <label> and such

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a few issues that needs dealing with. I have been trying for a few hours and searching the net but can find nothing relevant.

- List item width - as you can see the width of each answer is set to auto, and no matter where i set width in `<label>` `<li>` or `<ul>` the width stays auto
- Text in the question container will not center.

I have been following from examples and customizing everything to my needs. If you guys have suggestions on how to make this better as my coding skill are not great.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to include my jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u48spccg/

Comment: Could you post an example of whats not working?

Comment: can you please post an example of your html-code ?

Comment: there you go, thanks

Comment: @PaulLewis So you want to set the width for each answers?

Comment: Many people would advocate the usage of a table.

Comment: @Vega yes, and setting them to display:block makes the answers vertical when I need them to be horizontal

Comment: @PaulLewis See my answer and demo below and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your fiddle there is the CSS rule

```
.answers ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

and inline elements can't have their width specified.

As mentioned, you need to override this style with `display: inline-block`, or `float: left` (which implicitly gives it block display).

`display: block` without the floating will make them stack vertically as you have observed.

When it comes to the centering of the question text, a simple

```
.question {
  text-align: center; 
}
```

will do the trick. In your fiddle it looks a bit funny though as the parent it's centering relative to is very wide and is overflowing the page to the right.

Answer (score 1):

`<label>`, `<li>` and `<ul>` tags are `list-item` elements, and just as `inline` elements, you cannot set width to them, and it will not work... If you want to change their state, make them `display:block` or `display:inline-block`.

Comment: I think this is ok answer to that question, dunno who give minus.

Comment: Why was this minus? Correct answer to question.

Comment: Not my downvote, but --> `make them display:block or display:inline-block`

Comment: This answer is full of errors... `li` elements are not `inline`, they're `list-item`. `ul` elements are `block` and setting `display: inline` will not solve OP's issue, it *is* OP's issue.

Comment: Agree with @André Dion. ul and li are both blocks by default (and there is no element called "lu").

Comment: @Godisgood It is a typo. I think he meant `ul`. lets be nice to the new guy here..

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand why this is still being upvoted. Out of seven factual statements five are simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities:

add

```
label, ul, li{
    display: block;
}
```

OR

```
label, ul, li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

OR

```
label, ul, li{
    float: left;
}
```

all three solutions will affect the behavior of how these elements will be displayed.
For centering your text add `text-align: center` to your elements, but this will only work for block-elements. Inline-Elements just claim the space of it's content. Because of that there is no space for centering the content.

For your list-items, remove the `display:inline` and add `float:left` or add `display:inline-block` (without floating)

See [here](http://webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/) for further information

Comment: Your last option is redundant—`float` will trigger `display: block`.

Comment: will any of these options keep the answers horizontal? I tried block and they go vertical. Maybe I am not applying to the right classes

Comment: @PaulLewis Use `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

The elements are inline so setting the width won't work. You could try `inline-block`, but then you will end up setting a fixed width for the `li` and it won't look good if the text is small but the label width is wide.

Instead try setting `padding` to the label which should give enough space around the text. If you like add a margin to the li so that there is a space between each answer.

**DEMO:** **http://jsfiddle.net/s5493xvo/**

```
/* space between your question and answer */
.questionContainer .answers { margin: 5px; } 
/* space between each answer */
.questionContainer .answers li { margin-right: 5px; } 
/* space between the text and label */ 
.questionContainer .answers li label { padding: 5px 10px; }
```

I recommend you reading about box model at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model - This should help you understand the above solution better.

```js
// JavaScript and jQuery for interactive quiz follows
$(function(){
  // highlight question row on mouseover
  


$(function(){
      $('.answers label').click(function(e) {
            $('.answers label').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
});



  var S2CQuiz = {
    init: function(){
        // next question
        $('.btnNext').on('click', function(){
            // Make sure a radio box has been checked
            if ($('input[type=radio]:checked:visible').length == 0) {
                $('.errMsg').show().fadeOut(1200);        
                return false;
            }
            $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
            });
            var progBar = $('#progress');
            var numq = S2CQuiz.numQuestions();
            var progWidth = 0 / numq;
            progBar.width(progBar.width() + progWidth + 'px');
        });
        // previous question
        $('.btnPrev').on('click', function(){
            $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).prev().fadeIn(500);
            });
            var progBar = $('#progress');
            // Extract question number and calculate width
            var qString =  $(this).parents('.questionContainer').children()
                                  .first().children('strong').text();
            var numq = parseInt(qString.substr(9, 2));
            numq--;
            var progWidth = progBar.width() / numq;
            progBar.width(progBar.width() - progWidth + 'px');
        });
        // last question
        $('.btnShowResult').on('click', function(){
            // Make sure a radio box has been checked
            if ($('input[type=radio]:checked:visible').length == 0) {
                $('.errMsg').show().fadeOut(1200);        
                return false;
            }
            $('#progress').width(0);
            $('#progressContainer').hide();
        
            // Extract users answers to an array and call a function to check them
            var arr = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
            var ans = S2CQuiz.userAnswers = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                ans.push(arr[i].getAttribute('id'));
            }
            var results = S2CQuiz.checkAnswers();
            // Loop through the 'right' or 'wrong' array extracting the results
            var resultSet = '';
            var rightCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
               if (results[i] == "right") {
                   rightCount++;
                   resultSet += '<div> Question ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + results[i] + '</div>';
               } else {
                   var expid = '#' + 'exp' + (i + 1); 
                   var exp = $(expid).text();
                   resultSet += '<div class="red"> Question ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + results[i] 
                             + '<strong>' + exp + '</strong></div>';
               }
            }
            var numq = S2CQuiz.numQuestions();
            resultSet += '<div class="totalScore">You scored ' + rightCount + '/' +  numq + '</div>';
            $('#resultContainer').html(resultSet).show();
        });
    }, 
    answers: { q1: 'a', q2: 'a', q3: 'b' },
    // Check answers and output 'right' or 'wrong' to another array
    checkAnswers: function() {
        var arr = this.answers;
        var ans = this.userAnswers;
        var resultArr = [];
        for (var p in ans) {
            var x = parseInt(p) + 1;
            var key = 'q' + x;
            var flag = "wrong";
            if (ans[p] == 'q' + x + '-' + arr[key]) {
               flag = "right";
            }
            else {
               flag = "wrong";
            }
            resultArr.push(flag);
        }
        return resultArr;
    },
    // Calcualte number of question
    numQuestions: function() {
        var arr = this.answers;
        var x = 0;
        for (var p in arr) {
           if (p < 10) {
               x = parseInt(p.substr(1, 1));
           } else {
               x = parseInt(p.substr(1, 2));
           }
        }
        return x;
    }
  };
  S2CQuiz.init();
});
```

```css
/* space between your question and answer */
.questionContainer .answers { margin: 5px; } 
/* space between each answer */
.questionContainer .answers li { margin-right: 5px; } 
/* space between the text and label */ 
.questionContainer .answers li label { padding: 5px 10px; } 

label
{
  background-color: Sienna ;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right:auto; 
  margin-left:auto;
  width:50%;
}

label.active 
{
  background-color:Orchid ;
 

}

#textcont
{
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
 float: left
}

#header
{
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius:80px ;
  border-bottom-right-radius:80px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px;

  margin:0;
     /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";

}


.answers ul li 
{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: inline;
  margin-right:auto; 
  margin-left:auto;
  width:50%;
}

/* Reset browser styles */
h1, h2, p, div, ul, li, label, code, pre, body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
.txtStatusBar { 
  font-weight:bold;
  margin:auto;
 text-align: center
}
/* wrap main content */
#main {
 
  background-size: 100%;
  float:left;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height:70vh;
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px grey;
}
/* Quiz heading */
h1 { 
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  color:black;

}
/* Question container */
.questionContainer {
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 900px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding:3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px;
   /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";


}
/* Button container */
.btnContainer {
  margin:10px 0 10px 1%;
  width:98%;
}
.prev{float:left;}
.prev a, .next a {
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:2px 5px;
}
.prev a:hover, .next a:hover {
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #36648B;
  color:white !important;
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
.next, .btnShowResult {float:right;}
.clear {clear:both;}
/* Progress bar */
.txtStatusBar { 
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#progressContainer { 

  border:1px solid grey;
  height:20px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  padding:3px;
  width: 900px;
  border-radius:8px;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px;
   /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
#progress {
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 purple;
  height:20px;
  width:0;
  border-radius:5px;

}
/* Refined layout CSS */
.hide {display:none;}

.clear
{
  clear:both;
}

input {
  position:fixed;
  padding:0px;
  visibility: hidden;



}

#resultContainer {
  background:white;
 
 margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding:3px;
  width:900px;
  border-radius:8px;
}
#resultContainer div {line-height:20px;}
/* Error message */
.errMsg {
  color:red;
 margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center
 
}
/* Question explanation and score highlight */
.red {color:red;}
.totalScore{font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div class="questionContainer">
      <div class="question"><strong>Question 1 :</strong> What is my name?</div>
      <div class="answers" >
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
            <li style="width:500px"><label >Paul<input type="radio" id="q1-a" name="q1" /> </label></li>
            <li><label>Jim<input type="radio" id="q1-b" name="q1" /> </label></li>
            <li><label>Bob<input type="radio" id="q1-c" name="q1" /> </label></li>
            <li><label>John<input type="radio" id="q1-d" name="q1" /> </label></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hide red" id="exp1"> - My name is Paul you fool!</div>
      <div class="btnContainer">
        <div class="prev"></div>
        <div class="next"><a class="btnNext">Next ++</a></div>
          <span class="errMsg hide" style="text-align:center;"><strong>Please select an answer</strong></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer hide">
      <div class="question"><strong>Question 2 :</strong> Kildrummy is the best?</div>
      <div class="answers">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none"><li><label><input type="radio" id="q2-a" name="q2" /> true</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="radio" id="q2-b" name="q2" /> false</label></li></ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hide red" id="exp2"> - HOW DARE YOU.</div>
      <div class="btnContainer">
        <div class="prev"><a class="btnPrev">-- Prev</a></div>
        <div class="next"><a class="btnNext">Next ++</a></div>
          <span class="errMsg hide" style="text-align:center;"><strong>Please select an answer</strong></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer hide">
      <div class="question"><strong>Question 3 :</strong> hi?</div>
      <div class="answers">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><label><input type="radio" id="q3-a" name="q3" /> hi</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" id="q3-b" name="q3" /> hi</label></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hide red" id="exp3"> - hi.</div>
      <div class="btnContainer">
        <div class="prev"><a class="btnPrev">-- Prev</a></div>
        <div class="next"><a class="btnShowResult">Finish</a></div>
          <span class="errMsg hide" style="text-align:center;"><strong>Please select an answer</strong></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="progressContainer" style="display: block;">
      <div id="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide" id="resultContainer"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need to change them to block or inline-block.

Here's the modified jsfiddle with one option for style changes embedded inline:

```
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li style="width:500px;display:block;"><label style='display:block' >Paul<input type="radio" id="q1-a" name="q1" /> </label></li>
        <li style="width:500px;display:block;"><label style='display:block'>Jim<input type="radio" id="q1-b" name="q1" /> </label></li>
        <li style="width:500px;display:block;"><label style='display:block'>Bob<input type="radio" id="q1-c" name="q1" /> </label></li>
        <li style="width:500px;display:block;"><label style='display:block'>John<input type="radio" id="q1-d" name="q1" /> </label></li>
    </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bwy9tcze/

Per a comment you made:

> @Vega yes, and setting them to display:block makes the answers vertical when I need them to be horizontal

You'll need to either use inline-block to make them sit next to each other or do block with a float:left;  You may want to look into how grid system are built (e.g. Bootstrap 3) for some good examples.  If you need further clarification, let me know.